# unix_timestamp() returns an error in hive

Tags: timestamp, hive

while trying to set current timestamp in hive and use it later.
Gets the following error

```
hive> set start_time= unix_timestamp();
FAILED: Parse Error: line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'unix_timestamp' '(' ')'
```

Am i doing something wrong or is there any other way to capture current timestamp in hive?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a table if you want to use unix_timestamp,  in concrete terms:

```
select unix_timestamp() from any_existing_table LIMIT 1;
```

You can find more explanations here : [Get current unix_timestamp in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925330/get-current-unix-timestamp-in-hive)